# Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created

Tags: c#, code-coverage, dotcover

Running code coverage with dotcover sometimes dotcover cannot create the snapshot but the process finished successfully.

I attach the dotCover log after failing.

```
11:23:04 AM.677: Thread:33: Starting console app: "C:\Windows\system32\RegSvr32.exe" /s /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\dotCover\v2.6\Bin\JetBrains.Profiler.Core.Win.x64.dll"
11:23:04 AM.740: Thread:33: Console app exited with code [0]: "C:\Windows\system32\RegSvr32.exe" /s /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\dotCover\v2.6\Bin\JetBrains.Profiler.Core.Win.x64.dll"
11:23:04 AM.787: Thread:33: @[BaseHost] PdbServer TerminateRequestSent pid=1348
11:23:04 AM.787: Thread:33: @[BaseHost] PdbServer Exited pid=1348 exitCode=0
11:23:04 AM.787: Thread:33: @[BaseBridge] Deactivate
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:33: [CoverageSession#0] Executing 'finish' callback (configuration id: '')
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:33: [CoverageSession#0] Executing 'finish' callback after session lifetime termination (configuration id: '')
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:33: [CoverageSession#0] Setting SessionFinishedEvent
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:1: [CoverageSession#0] SessionFinishedEvent was received
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:1: Coverage session finished [5/9/2014 11:23:04 AM]
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:1: Index Files = 
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:1: Aborted = False
11:23:04 AM.802: Thread:1: Exit Code = 0
11:23:04 AM.833: Thread:1: EXCEPTION: Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created
Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created ---> JetBrains.dotCover.ConsoleRunner.CommandExecutionException: Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created
   at JetBrains.dotCover.ConsoleRunner.Impl.Commands.Cover.CoverCommand.DoExecute(IWorkspace workspace)
   at JetBrains.dotCover.ConsoleRunner.Impl.Commands.Cover.CoverCommand.Execute()
   at JetBrains.dotCover.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunnerBackend.Execute(IEnumerable`1 args, Func`1 componentContainerGetter)
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack



11:23:04 AM.833: Thread:1: Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created. 
11:23:04 AM.833: Thread:1: Console Runner execution finished
11:23:04 AM.833: Thread:1: Shutting down shell...
11:23:04 AM.849: Thread:1: [JetEnvironment] IApplicationDescriptor::JetEnvironment::Products-- 1v0: JetBrains.dotCover.ShellBase.DotCoverApplicationDescriptorLite.
11:23:04 AM.896: Thread:1: [RunningProducts] KeyValuePair`2::RunsProducts::ProductContainersComposed-- 1v0: “[JetBrains.dotCover.ShellBase.DotCoverApplicationDescriptorLite, Container: Product(dotCover)]”.
11:23:04 AM.911: Thread:30: process [1348] 'JetBrains.Profiler.CorePdbServer.x64' has exited with code 0
11:23:04 AM.974: Thread:1: [MW] OnWmActivate Detached.
11:23:04 AM.974: Thread:1: dotCover 2.6 Version=2.6.608.466, Built=2013-12-09T21:17:38, Configuration=“CLR4 ConsoleRunnerApplication Full PublicMode”
11:23:05 AM.021: Thread:1: [RunningProducts] KeyValuePair`2::RunsProducts::ProductContainersNonComposed-- 1v0: “[JetBrains.dotCover.ShellBase.DotCoverApplicationDescriptorLite, Container: Product(dotCover)]”.
11:23:05 AM.021: Thread:1: [RunsProducts] IApplicationDescriptor::RunsProducts::ProductsToRun-- 1v0: JetBrains.dotCover.ShellBase.DotCoverApplicationDescriptorLite.
11:23:05 AM.021: Thread:1: [ReportsProductsAllowedToRun] IProductCanBeStarted::JetEnvironment::IProductCanBeStarted[]-- v: JetBrains.Application.Env.Components.SuspendResumeProductCanBeStarted (ACK).
11:23:05 AM.021: Thread:1: [ReportsProductsAllowedToRun] IProductCanBeStarted::JetEnvironment::IProductCanBeStarted[]-- v: JetBrains.UI.License.UITimeBombComponent (ACK).
11:23:05 AM.021: Thread:1: [ReportsProductsAllowedToRun] IProductCanBeStarted::JetEnvironment::IProductCanBeStarted[]-- v: JetBrains.dotCover.Infrastructure.Environment.Model.LiberalLicenseCheckComponent (ACK).
```

Comment: What about your test results? What do they show? Did your tests run successfully?

Comment: Yes, in both cases all my test finish successfully .

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and the problem was really simple, when you run dotcover, your are listening the local prosses, and I was executing my automation test pointing to a server, so dotcover can't listen and track the cover. I just point to my local environment to resolve.